# Cannot scroll content in a DIV for seconds in mobile phone browsers if touched body before it

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I created a web page like this, I set the `BODY` to `position: fixed` and `width:100%; height: 100%`. The cyan part is the `header` of the page and the list is the part that I want it to be scrollable.

I am encountering a problem is that the list part cannot be scrolled for a short while, maybe 2 seconds, after I touched the cyan part.

I tried to call `preventDefault` on `touchmove` on `body` and `header`, it sometimes worked well but not all the time. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: First things first ... With that rep you already should know, that debugging images is hard, if not even impossible. Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: You can just [`.focus()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp) the element you want and it'll be the new **document.activeElement**.